# Bare git repo not cloneable after commit pushed

Tags: git, git-http-backend

I have a problem with own git server on which I only use the git-http-backend.
I discover that after I create the empty repository on the server with this:

```
git init --bare
```

I can clone the empty repo on any host with any user,

```
git clone https://example.com/nameOfRepo.git
```

but after I make a change the repository is only working with one host.

```
git add filename
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

In conclusion after change is made the repository is assigned to one host. I can't clone the repository to another host.
Do You have idea what is wrong?

**EDIT:**

On server I do:

```
mkdir repoName.git
cd repoName.git
git init --bare
```

On first host I make:

```
git clone https://example.com/repoName.git
touch filename.txt
git add filename
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push
```

After that I try to clone repo to second machine with that:

```
git clone https://example.com/repoName.git
```

and this failed with this:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

After that I try to clone repo on first machine but to another directory:

```
mkdir repoNameNew.git
cd repoNameNew.git
git clone https://example.com/repoName.git
```

but this is failed too with

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: What change did you make?

Comment: I add file and make commit, then push.

Comment: We're not psychic... please may you amend the question with the change you made.?

Comment: So by "is only working with one host." you mean that you are not able to clone the repository from another machine?!

Comment: Not only. Even if I init local repo and add remote, I can't pull anything. But I found that I have the 504 error (Gateway timeout) but it is not possible because I check two machine in both way and always if one make change it blocks another. The second issue is that even if i want clone the repo to another directory on which git is working I can't do that. Very strange and confussed for me.

Comment: If you use `git clone`, you don't have to use `git init`. `git clone` initializes a repository, sets the remote and fetches from it (see [documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)).

Comment: I know. But the second try was create local repo and pull the changes to it from remote.

Comment: It's still not clear what exactly you did and what the problem is. You used `git init --bare` and then `git clone` to create a local copy. You made changes, committed and pushed. Now you cannot clone the repository any more? Which error message are you getting *excactly* ? Can you provide the exact git commands you used?

Comment: I edit my question to be more clear.